# Prove that $(x^2+2x+1)$ is continuous by using a $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ argument

Tags: calculus, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta, triangle-inequality

I want to prove that the following function is continuous with an Epsilon Delta Argument.
$$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \;  (x^2+2x+1)$$

So I started with
$$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y) \right\rvert= \left\lvert (x^2+2x+1) - (y^2+2y+1) \right\rvert = \left\lvert (x^2+2x)-(y^2+2y) \right\rvert$$

$$\le 2\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{x^2-y^2}{2} \right\rvert + \left\lvert x- y\right\rvert \right\rvert $$
$$\le 2\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{2} \right\rvert + \delta \right\rvert$$
$$= 2\left\lvert \frac{\left\lvert(x+y)(x-y)\right\rvert}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
$$ \le 2\left\lvert \frac{\left\lvert(x+y)\delta\right\rvert}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
$$= 2\left\lvert \frac{[\left\lvert(x-y)\right\rvert+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert]\delta}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
Now I define $\delta \le1.$
$$= 2\left\lvert \frac{(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert)\delta}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
$$= \left\lvert(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert)\delta + 2\delta \right\rvert $$
$$= \delta \left\lvert(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert) + 2 \right\rvert $$
$$= \delta \left\lvert\left\lvert2y\right\rvert + 3 \right\rvert = \epsilon $$
And so my $\delta$ is $\frac{\epsilon}{\left\lvert\left\lvert2y\right\rvert + 3 \right\rvert}$ and $\delta \le 1$

Can anyone tell my if this is correct or where I went wrong I am studying for exam. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything looks okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to factor the number $2$ out of your estimate. But the following may be a more natural way to *think* about how to find a needed $\delta$.

Notice that $$
|x^2+2x-y^2-2y|\le|x+y||x-y|+2|x-y|=(|x+y|+2)|x-y|
\tag{1}
$$

Suppose you want to show that your function is continuous at $y$. If $|x-y|<\delta$, you want
$$
(|x+y|+2)|x-y|\le \epsilon. \tag{2}
$$

On the other hand,

$$
(|x+y|+2)|x-y|\le (|x-y|+2|y|+2)|x-y|\le (\delta+2|y|+2)\delta\tag{3}
$$

So if you let $\delta<1$ and $(2|y|+3)\delta<\epsilon$, you get what you want.

To wrap things up, set $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|y|+3})$.

---

Your solution is ok except for several places. See below.

> So I started with (*assuming $|x-y|<\delta$ *)
> $$\left\lvert f(x)-f(y) \right\rvert= \left\lvert (x^2+2x+1) - (y^2+2y+1) \right\rvert = \left\lvert (x^2+2x)-(y^2+2y) \right\rvert$$

> $$\le 2\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{x^2-y^2}{2} \right\rvert + \left\lvert x- y\right\rvert \right\rvert $$
> $$< 2\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{2} \right\rvert + \delta \right\rvert$$
> $$= 2\left\lvert \frac{\left\lvert(x+y)(x-y)\right\rvert}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
> $$\color{red}{\le} 2\left\lvert \frac{\left\lvert(x+y)\delta\right\rvert}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
> $$= 2\left\lvert \frac{[\left\lvert(x-y)\right\rvert+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert]\delta}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
> Now if I *set* $\delta \le1$ then
> $$= 2\left\lvert \frac{(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert)\delta}  {2} + \delta \right\rvert $$
> $$= \left\lvert(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert)\delta + 2\delta \right\rvert $$
> $$= \delta \left\lvert(1+\left\lvert2y\right\rvert) + 2 \right\rvert $$
> $$= \delta \left\lvert\left\lvert2y\right\rvert + 3 \right\rvert = \epsilon $$
> And so my $\delta$ is $\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{\left\lvert2y\right\rvert + 3 })$.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Second, why do you add the absolute Value of y at (3) ? and is the solution I had also correct or only min(1, epsilon/abs(y)+3)?

Comment: @Bruno: that's just the triangle inequality $|x+y|=|x-y+y|\le |x-y|+|y|$.

Comment: Oh okay, I got it. So would both solutions work? (I mean your's is clearly shorter and easier than mine)

Comment: @Bruno: your solution looks okay to me except some minor places. I will come back soon.

Comment: I upvoted it :) . Thank you for your help already!

Comment: @Bruno: I edited my answer. Let me know if you have more questions to accept the answer.

Comment: One more question why is it once a strict < when w substitute the term for delta and the other time its $\le$ (in red)

Comment: @Bruno: simply speaking, the strict inequality is used in the definition of continuity; you can change it in *some* places to get an equivalent definition. The non-strict $\le$ is used since (i) it is correct; (ii) so that you don't need to check whether it is $=$ or $<$.

Comment: Ah okay I see so basically we could always write $\le$ ?

Comment: @Bruno: that's right. Except that one needs to be careful if the left hand side is $0$. Being strictly positive and nonnegative sometimes are very different.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much @mrsamy ! I already gave you the check!

Comment: @Bruno: you are welcome! Glad to help!

Comment: Sorry to ask again but it is not completely clear to me how $ \left\lvert x+y \right\rvert = \left\lvert x+y-y\right\rvert$  in your comment above

Comment: @Bruno: sorry about that. That was a small error. I will correct it right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118468/discussion-between-bruno-and-mrsamy).

Answer (score 0):

As a comparison I did this

$$
\left| x^2 + 2x + 1 - y^2 - 2y - 1 \right| < |x-y|^2 + (2|y| + 2)|x - y| < \epsilon
$$

And I defined $\delta$ as the strictly positive solution of $\delta^2 + (2|y| + 1)\delta = \epsilon$, which you can easily show it exists for every $\epsilon > 0$.